# google Visualization Organizational Chart collapse to second row

Tags: javascript, orgchart, google-visualization

By using google Visualization Organizational Chart I have built my Organization chart, basically it is a big chart so I am trying to collapse the sub roots until the second row.

I have gone through the API and I found the **collapse(row, collapsed)** here it is asking for the row id by my row id's are improper, so this my issue.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

i have achieved this by method getChildrenIndexes(row);

```
var allIndexes = chart.getChildrenIndexes(0);
            for (var i = 0; i < allIndexes.length; i++) {

                chart.collapse(allIndexes[i], true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `collapse` method uses the row index of the node in the DataTable, not the row id.  To collapse a node from the 3rd row of the DataTable, you would use:

```
myOrgChart.collapse(2, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, for every node they will have row index in most cases row index will be in an order 0 1 2 3, but in my case the row index is improper like 0 4 5 1 2 3  0 is root. So I resolved my issue by using below answer.